# Internal Server error while consuming rest service in C#

Tags: c#, rest

I am  bit new in rest service

I have service as below

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,UriTemplate="AuthenticateJSON/?username=username&password=password")]
    public Response.Authenicate Authenticate(string username,string password)
    {
        var returnObject = new Authenicate();
        try
        {
            returnObject.Response = "True";
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionObject)
        {
            returnObject.IsError = true;
            returnObject.ErrorMessage = exceptionObject.Message;

        }
        return returnObject;
    }
```

And I consume Service by below code

```
   string input = @"{'himanshu','password'}";
        var newUser = new User();
        newUser.username = "username";
        newUser.password = "username";

        var input = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(newUser);
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:20620/Services/User/OperationActiveDirectory.svc/AuthenticateJSON/?username=username&password=password");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";//POST/GET
        string responseText = "";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(input);//any parameter
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

but i am facing below error  while execution[image]

Could some one suggest me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: It's strange, have you tried fidler or any REST client requester to debug the backend server ?

Comment: Yes, i have test backend server , it working fine their